# What is standard dropout with weight averaging?

Tags: neural-networks, dropout

I understand that standard dropout is switching neurons on and off during training, to minimize overfitting.

I came across standard dropout with *weight averaging* [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02142.pdf) (Figure 2a), what is this suppose to mean?

Cheers

Comment: Where have you seen it? Could you provide a reference?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your comment, I edited my reference, cheers

Answer (score 1):

I presume you made sense out of it since then, but for those who may encounter this question: if $p_i$ is the dropout probability for layer $i$, weight averaging is about multiplying the weights in layer $i$ by $1-p_i$ at test time. Indeed, dropout is activated during training time, but switched off at test time, so this ensures layer activations scale as expected.